# Trying install PyYAML on Mac

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I get followig error when I type `import yaml` in python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
```

I installed `libyaml` via `brew` and `PyYAML` via `pip`

```
pip list | grep -i yaml
PyYAML (3.12)
```

Everything looks ok but still `import yaml` fails

---

**PS** I do not have solution. But most likely it was due `brew`
I have 2 pythons and 2 pips. It seems default pip was installing in location where only brew's python can see it.

Also I reset permissions package folders

**PSS**

```
which -a python
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
which -a pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of the exception? All that tells us is that it didn't work, which is unhelpful to say the least.

Comment: Add the output of `which -a python` and `which -a pip` to your question.

Comment: I have updated post by adding `which`

Comment: How are you starting `python` when you run `import yaml`?